# Angular2 ngModel not working

Tags: angular

I am trying to bind `ngModel` from text input but it's is not working.
Here is my code:

**Template:**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="message">
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Component:**

```
export class Component implements OnInit {
  message:string

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.message);
  }
}
```

Always getting undefined value. How to bind value from the text input to variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing ngForm

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="message" [(ngModel)]="message">
      </div>
      <input type="button">
    </form>

export class Component implements OnInit {
  message:string

   ngOnInit() {
this.message = "test";
}

  onSubmit(form: ngForm) {
    console.log(form.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: you're not assigning any value to message

Comment: I have the same code as here but message is allways empty object. I noticed that when I open my page with this form (localhost:4200/page/something) url was change to localhost:4200, but when i remove [(ngModel)]="message" url is correct

Comment: have you imported the ngForm from angular/forms ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145703/discussion-between-bluray-and-arun-kumaresh).

Answer (score 7):

you have to give `input` a `name` property when using template-driven form.

```
<input type="text" name="message" [(ngModel)]="message">
```

refer this simple **[plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/XYJS7rJQSKnugwQRNSpO?p=preview)**.

Comment: idk why but I always seem to miss this.  also applies for non-input elements as well in case you are using other angular directives or third party inputs.